# Can I dynamically append an og tag and render it?

Tags: php, javascript, html, facebook

I'm trying to make a link to my website and facebook, putting some meta data on it! My target is to manage this data :

```
<meta property="og:title" content="MY_PAGE_TITLE" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="MY_DESCRIPTION_TEXT" />
```

Unfortunatly, my web application (on PHP) is not well structured, and I haven't define a correct MVC! It is very procedural, so the infos that I should put on these meta tag are extracted, from database, after the rendering of the main html header section.

So, what I tried is this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('head').append("<meta property=\"og:title\" content=\"MY_PAGE_TITLE\" />");
    $('head').append("<meta property=\"og:description\" content=\"MY_DESCRIPTION_TEXT\" />");
</script>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<fb:like href="<?=$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]?>" send="false" layout="button_count" width="130" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

But in fact, it doesnt works! I mean, append meta tag on the head and than try render it.

Do you know some strategies to do it? I'll avoid the option on insert directly them on the head, because, as I says, the text I'd like to insert is get after the head section (due to a wrong organization of the website).

I believe in another solution, hope you know one!

Comment: Appending `<meta>` tags after the document is loaded may not do any good, given the nature of `<meta>` tags.

Answer (score 5):

Sad but no other way than to change your structure. The reason for the og: tags not being processed even with your javascript is that facebook doesn't render the javascript. It just asks for the page and reads the OG tags from the top just like static HTML would be.

Your only option is to change your structure and load your content before the output. You don't need to change to MVC for that, juste loading your content BEFORE the head will save you heaps of work and still work...

Comment: In fact, if I append the meta tags on the head, they should be avaiable on facebook rendering (that it is executed after the append). I don't understand why it shouldn't works :)

Comment: @markzzz Facebook's parser doesn't execute JavaScript. At all. Without JavaScript, nothing's being appended **anywhere**.

Comment: I think so! How can it get meta tag? Anyway, without JS, the Facebook Plugins won't work at all, so I don't mind about this :)

Comment: Look, if you build OG tags with JavaScript, Facebook will not see them. Period. You might as well just leave them out.

Comment: @ceejayoz : ok! My question is : why? In fact the elements are appended to the DOM...! I'd like to know why (and how) it ignores them :)

Comment: Javascript is a technology run by a browser. When facebook gets your page, it's not a browser that is doing it, it's a PHP function called file_get_contents(). This function doesn't render the page nor executes the javascript, it is only used to get the content of the rendered php page or the html it contains. Sure there will be javascript in there, but facebook will not execute it. It will simply parse the page for XFBML and OG tags and use them. If your information is tucked inside Javascript, it will see it's there and ignore it...

Comment: "In fact the elements are appended to the DOM." By JavaScript. Facebook's parser **doesn't execute JavaScript**. I'm not sure how much clearer we can be.